# Fading paths in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to create fading paths in d3.js, similar to the wind lines in the famous earth wind visualization:

http://earth.nullschool.net/

In principle, it seems like I could create a path with a lot of waypoints and transition each of the end segments toward transparency, but that seems hacky. Any better ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: If you use small, filled circles you can build something from [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062544).

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on the example offered, here is [a block](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/5c0ab03ab07817d8d953) on a reduced version. It is based on canvass as mentioned.  The block illustrates the technique that I mentioned in my comments where the rendering engine is aggressively challenged which gives the blur effect for free.  Click on the <kbd>normal</kbd> button to change to synchronous redraws and you can see that the blurring effect dissapears.  This is achieved in the following code...

```
            function run() {
              paused = false;
              then = Date.now();
              now = then;

              particles.forEach(function(p) {
                p.t = now + (Math.random() - 1) * duration;
              });

              d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
                var i = -1, n = particles.length;
                var f = format(" >8.1f"), f3 = format(" >8.4f");
                var normal = modeButton.text() == "normal", t;

                if(normal) {
                  // clear the shadow context and copy the current context to it
                  offscreenContext.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                  offscreenContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, width, height)
                  //clear the current context and try to jam the previous version
                  //back on top of the drawing activities
                  //lovely chaos ensues
                  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                  context.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
                }
                else {
                  //allow the
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                    context.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
                    offscreenContext.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                }

                now = elapsed + then;
                //iterate the transition for each county
                while(++i < n) {
                  var p = particles[i], t = (now - p.t) / duration;
                  if(t > 1) {
                    p.t += duration * Math.floor(t);
                    p.y = p.d.centroid[1] + (true ? (Math.random() - .5) * 2 : 0);
                  }
                  else if(t > 0) {
                    if(!normal){
                      offscreenContext.fillStyle = "rgba(" + p.r + "," + p.g + "," + p.b + "," + mirror(1 - t) + ")";
                      offscreenContext.fillRect(p.x + (t - .5) * p.v * 2 - .75, p.y - .75, 2.5, 2.5);
                    } else {
                      context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + p.r + "," + p.g + "," + p.b + "," + mirror(1 - t) + ")";
                      context.fillRect(p.x + (t - .5) * p.v * 2 - .75, p.y - .75, 1.5, 1.5);
                    }
                  }
                }

                return paused;
              }, 0, now);
            }
          });
```

Comment: Holy crap! This is great, but I'm still a little lost about what's actually happening. It looks like you're drawing to `context` in normal mode and `offscreenContext` in synchronized mode. Then you just copy the current image to the offscreenContext and draw from that. Where is the engine being aggressively challenged? Also, how do you debug drawing to the console when you have no access to the DOM?

Comment: Yes, they did it with two contexts so they could avoid a progressive update as it scanned the nodes; so they update the offscreenContext then flash it across, or at least you would think that that would be the idea, but somewhere along the way they worked out that if you try to jam the offscreenContext down the throat of the rendering engine _while simultaneously_ doing a live re-draw on the visible context then you get a nice interpolation of that mess, resulting in the blur effect. Free of charge!

Comment: If you run a profile in the Chrome dev tools and check out the flame graph, you can see the fragmentation of the drawImage and fillRectangle calls and how it varies between the two modes. But mostly I'm just guessing what's going on. I'd be interested in other views on it...

Comment: Yeah, I just saw this: http://codepen.io/akm2/full/rHIsa, which does something similar. I'll see if I can't do it with D3 and then try out the canvas version.

Comment: @CoolBlue Thank you for sharing this great answer, I used it to guide me starting to visualize the path for bus movement as in this link
https://vimeo.com/5368967

Comment: @CoolBlue do you think it is a good start to begin with? or do you recommend another example to use it fo this purpose?

Comment: Wow, nice! I’m not a leading expert these days so maybe there are other ways but, it looks great in your example. I reverse-engineered a NYT interactive page. That’s where I got the technique.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar effect implemented in d3.js, though the code is compressed. You might find a way to reverse engineer it or find an uncompressed source.

It seems to me like each arcs is drawn only once it's the **color** that has a transition applied with a gradient that changes over time, and then is removed.  I can't quite tell if all arcs share the same gradient and just start from different places, and appear at different times.  That might be a great shortcut.

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/11/11/sunday-review/counties-moving.html

There's a presentation how this came to be, so perhaps they've talked about the tech elsewhere?

http://www.slideshare.net/openjournalism/amanda-cox-visualizing-data-at-the-new-york-times

(Quick note, I realize this isn't actually an answer, just needed more space than the comments section allows)

Comment: The first example is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't find the paths anywhere in the DOM. Could it be that they're being drawn directly on the canvas, and not on the SVG element?

Comment: @juniper- you are correct: the first example is using canvas, not svg.  It's just filling small rectangles on the canvas and manually doing the opacity and position transitions.

Comment: Yup, a more clear implementation can be found here http://hint.fm/wind/wind-bundle.js. I wonder how much slower it would be if it had to update the DOM instead of drawing directly to canvas. I guess I'll find out :)

Comment: I suspect that if you do it with DOM elements it will be much heavier. The election map uses a cheap (but super-effective) trick to achieve the blurring FOC: by overwhelming the rendering engine.  If you did it with svg you would need to run transitions on the particles to do that and that would be ex$pen$ive.